# Persisting objects with references to other objects

Tags: design-patterns, orm, architecture, dao

I'm working on a rather simple CRUD application with web interface. I'm using the generic DAO pattern in the persistence layer. The interface of my generic DAO looks like this:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {

    void create( T entity ) throws CannotPersistException;
    T findById( Long id ) throws NotFoundException;
    Collection<T> findAll();
    void update( T entity ) throws CannotPersistException, NotFoundException;
    void delete( Long id ) throws CannotPersistException, NotFoundException;
}
```

This interface is implemented using JPA, but I also have an in-memory implementation, mainly for testing purposes. **I don't have any other classes in the persistence layer**, I just create one instance of this DAO for every domain class.

The problem I'm facing is how to properly persist an object that has references to other objects that also need persisting. **I know that cascading in JPA would solve this without requiring me to add new classes to my persistence layer.** However, that would make me dependent on a specific implementation (and would also break my in-memory DAO implementation).

Right know, I'm using a service layer to manage the DAO classes and I solve the problem by **working with multiple DAOs.** I'll show an example:

```
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService {

    private GenericDAO<Player> playerDAO;
    private GenericDAO<Club> clubDAO;

    //constructor ommited

    public Player addNewPlayer( Player player, Long clubId ) throws NotFoundException,
            CannotPersistException {
        Club club = clubDAO.findById( clubId );
        player.setClub( club );
        playerDAO.create( player );
        club.addPlayer( player );
        clubDAO.update( club );
        return player;
    }

    //... other methods

}
```

The first disadvantage of this approach is that it makes my domain model anemic - the majority of methods are just getters and setters and most of the business logic is in the service layer.

I've found the other disadvantage when testing the application - **I can't really test the GenericDao class in isolation** if I want to use Club objects that have their collection fields populated with Player objects.
I would need to persist the Player object first so I can add it to the Club object so I can pass that to the GenericDao under test.

I've been looking through Fowler's PoEAA book for a solution, but I'm a little confused where O/R framework like Hibernate fits within the patterns he describes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use an in-memory DataSource**

It seems that you'd be better off using an in-memory DataSource rather than reinventing a workaround for JPA cascade. I'd suggest you look at configuring your test environment to allow you to select a different DataSource that targets an in-memory HSQLDB instance. You can then annotate your domain objects to cascade and test away to your hearts content. Here's a Spring context that demonstrates a simple configuration:

```
  <bean id="testDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test"/>
    <property name="user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>
```

Your test code can have a Factory that creates certain scenarios that you wish to test (using collections of transient domain objects until they reach the DAO which will populate their primary key fields). Since you may find yourself adding many potential duplicates into your test datasets you should consider adding a UUID field into your domain objects to allow them to be differentiated when the primary key is null. Typically this is just a lazily-loaded getUUID() method that is persisted alongside the other fields. You could even consider using it as your primary key since the chances of a collision are infinitesimal by definition.

In addition, I would approach the testing by having both a JDBC connection and the DAO JPA connection. You look at the state of the database for asserting through JDBC connection and you do your updates through your DAO connection.

**Anaemic domain objects is not an anti-pattern**

Depending on your strategy for domain modelling, there's nothing specifically wrong with anaemic domain objects. For example, you could have a bunch of fine-grained business objects that perform state change operations on the domain objects according to business rules. Essentially you'd have a Unit of Work/Command/DTO style approach with your service layer providing an Application Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

in C# I would probably consider to create an attribute which tells the dao if a property should be treated as part of the parent ("child"). I know there is something similar in Java, but I can't remember how it is called.

Sorry, it's C#:

```
class Club
{
  [ChildEntity]
  List<Player> Players { get; private set; }
}
```

It needs some reflection to find all the children and its children. If you don't like this, you could just consider to write an interface which returns the children:

```
class Club : IComplexEntity
{
  List<Player> Players { get; private set; }

  public IEnumerable<object> EntityChildren { get { return Players; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I'm facing is how to
>   properly persist an object that has
>   references to other objects that also
>   need persisting. I know that cascading
>   in JPA would solve this without
>   requiring me to add new classes to my
>   persistence layer. **However, that would
>   make me dependent on a specific
>   implementation** (and would also break
>   my in-memory DAO implementation).

You do realise that JPA is the Java standard for persistence and it is not an actual implementation. To use JPA you still need a PersistenceProvider (the implementation) but you can choose between several implementations (Toplink, Hibernate, etc).

I think you should use JPA Cascade here.

Comment: I know that JPA has different implementations. But let's say I would like to implement the persistence layer using iBatis.

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic type (the DOA) but the behaviour you need to implement is not generic.  It's like trying to put a square peg in a round hole: it's never going to work.

Some possible aproaches:

**Be specific**: if it was me, i'd be using types which defines specific things: a `Club` would have (just thinking of possible examples) an `address`, a `DJ` would have a `Genre / Style`.

Yes I'd end up with lot sof classes, but each class would have one job, and would do that well.  Because they were seperate they'd be isolated from change - which is bascially the proble you now have.

**Use inheritance**: if all your classes have these basic things in common then can you use that as a base, and handle the rest separately?

**Use multiple interfaces**: a bit like the inheretance but different.  You retain the existing interface which handles basics; you then define additional interfaces for additional behaviours.  When an object comes in that needs some action performed on it evaluate what interfaces it implements and process them in turn.  You also retain the option to change your existing interface to better support this approach - if that makes sense.

You can probably mix and match some of these options or bits of them.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your point, but generic DAO is not an uncommon pattern and implementing it using an ORM framework like JPA is quite easy: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html